# Packet Sender: in coming pocket is not displayed. What do I have to change?

Tags: packet-sniffers

I am using Pocket Send on Windows 10 to send and check udp pocket.  It shows only the out going pocket, but not showing incoming ones.

I think I am missing something hear.  What do I have to do to display the incoming ones.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packets sent to the broadcast address (255.255.255.255) will be returned to sender, so your machine is receiving those packets - but your OS may discard the packet if you are not listening on that port.

Check if your machine is listening on port '5500' that you specified by running the command `netstat -an` within command prompt. If it is not listening on that port, either change the port you are sending the packet to to a port that is listening or open the port for listening.